# How can I bookmark a video from other site to youtube?

Tags: youtube

How can I bookmark a video from other site to youtube ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [youtube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html)

> Adding information via HTTP POST
>
> The API returns the following response
>   codes for requests to add resources
>   such as ratings, comments, video
>   responses, complaints, **favorite**
>   videos, playlists, playlist entries,
>   subscriptions and contacts.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html